# Confused about how I should handle my looping thread

Tags: java

I'm currently confused on how I should solve a certain problem:

I have a thread, whose `run()` method approximately looks like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    running = true;

    while(running) {
        foo(x);
        draw(x);
    }
}
```

Now this foo does something with variable `x`.

In the main thread theres a listener executing a method, which also changes `x`

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    bar(x);
}
```

The problem is now, that sometimes `x` gets modified by the `bar(x)` method, while `foo(x)` also changes `x`, which messes `x` up.

What I think could be done to fix this is for the listener, when firing, to wait for the loop to reach its end, execute its method and `bar(x)` while letting the thread wait and then notify the thread to let it continue looping after that.

I'm not very experienced with thread-handling though and would appreciate it, if someone helped me out. Sorry if this problem is really easy to solve and I just can't see the solution.

Comment: which for loop? If it reaches its end, how could it continue looping after that? Why are you sharing a thread-unsafe object (x) between threads? Or at the very least, why don't you synchronize on x, to make sure only one (cooperating) thread accesses it at a time?

Comment: You have to give us more details on what you're trying to achieve. You can simply synchronize using the x object, but we cannot be sure if this is what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I just had to synchronize the methods of `x`, which got called by the loop and the listener.

I should've represented the accessing of `x` by saying `x.foo()` and `x.bar()`, sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

You should make **x** an **AtomicInteger** (a thread-safe wrapper for Integers) and use it's methods to update and retrieve it in **bar()**, **foo()**, and **draw()**.

Some of the key methods here are **incrementAndGet()** (like **++x**), **getAndIncrement()** (like **x++**).  More here at the JavaDocs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Java 8 added a whole lot more to that interface for atomically doing larger calculations as well.

**AtomicInteger** may not be the correct type.  I'm guessing it based on guessing that **x** is an **int** in your example.